# Micronaut's HTTP client keeps throwing HttpClientResponseException even when disabled

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client

I have a simple Micronaut `3.4.2` application. I'm trying to use the `HttpClient` to test some (HTTP) resources. I've disabled the default behavior for responses that throw `HttpClientResponseException`, but still, I'm getting that exception back no matter what.

This is the content of `application-test.yaml` under `../src/test/resources/`:

```yaml
micronaut:
  http:
    client:
      exception-on-error-status: false
  server:
    port: -1
```

The test case looks like:

```kotlin
@MicronautTest(environments = [Environment.TEST])
internal class ControllerTest {
  @Inject
  @field:Client("/api/resource")
  private lateinit var client: HttpClient

  @Test
  fun get_WhenRecordDoesNotExist() {
    val id = UUID.randomUUID()
    val request = HttpRequest.GET<Customer>("/$id").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
    val response = client.toBlocking().exchange(request, String::class.java)
    Assertions.assertThat(response.status).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  }
}
```

Based on [this](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/pull/2372/) pull request, with `micronaut.http.client.exception-on-error-status` set to `false` it should work.

Am I missing something or is this still not supported? Are there any other solutions for this — I wouldn't like to use any other HTTP client.

---

##### UPDATE

I [opened an issue](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/7253) in their issue tracker for this.